# Handling form content with JavaScript and Perl

Tags: javascript, perl

I have a music project in Perl which also requires some JavaScript but I seem to be stuck.
I need to execute a program (ffplay) as a command-line application so it runs without displaying a GUI window. The Perl handles the server end of things (sqlite database access). I need JavaScript because I display track names as a button, which when clicked is supposed to run 'ffplay' to play the track named in the button code. But the button click requires JavaScript.

When I click a track name button, it only displays the first track, no matter which one I
click.

The following code extracts track names from the DB.

```
    $sth=$dbh->prepare (qq{select track from tracks where 
artistid=$ArtistID and cdid=$cdID order by track});
    $sth->execute();
    while(@records=$sth->fetchrow_array()) {
         $Track=$records[0];
print<<EndHTML;
<script>
var form=window.document.forms[0]
function process(form) {
        alert ("Track: " + form.elements.Track.value)
    }
</script>
EndHTML
        print qq{<form name="Player">};
        print qq{<input type="button" onClick="process(this.form)" name="Track" value="$Track"><br/>};
        print qq{</form>};
    }
    $sth->finish();
```

Comment: How do you call the CGI script? Please show more context to clarify your question. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: All the code is in 1 Perl script. It accesses the DB to create an HTML page of tracks as clickable buttons.

Comment: you haven't posted the whole script but it seems like you might be redefining `process` again and again for each row in the database. naming dozens of functions the same thing probably isn't going to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

Changed the JavaScript function :

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
function process(value) {
    var form =document.Player
        alert ("Track: " + value)
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="Player">
<button onClick="process(this.value)" name="Track1" value="[01] Evenfall.flac">[01] Evenfall.flac</button><br/>
<button onClick="process(this.value)" name="Track2" value="[02] 6am.flac">[02] 6am.flac</button><br/>
<button onClick="process(this.value)" name="Track3" value="[03] Cut.flac">[03] Cut.flac</button><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

Now the alert correctly tells me which button was clicked.